# How to use logback on Cloudbees

Tags: logging, deployment, lift, logback, cloudbees

I would like to know if it's possible to use my own logback configuration on Cloubees,
I have a `default.logback.xml` file that works perfectly fine in local, but once I deploy to Cloudbees its being ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Logging in CloudBees is via stdout and stderror - these are piped via syslog-ng to various systems (not all of which are file based) - so you can configure logging things as you want - but if you want your logs managed - it is best to ensure that things end up in stdout and stderr.

Comment: so logging with library like log4j is not supported on cloudbees ?

Comment: no - we and others use that all the time - its just if you want it to be collected by the cloudbees logging services (either the default one, papertrail and more) - you need to configure it to ultimately put output to stdout and stderr - where the result will be captured for you.

Comment: is RollingFileAppender and storing logs on files is supported on cloudbees ?

Comment: no - if you log to stdout then it is done for you - you don't need to roll logs, that is the whole point of using stdout - let the platform do it. You do NOT need to log to files - I repeat - log to stdout NOT to files!

Comment: the whole point of storing in files is to have archiving for logs but seems that papertrails is doing that for me.

Comment: Exactly. The log files are not backed up - there is one per instance in a cluster etc - vs a logging service, that is decoupled from where the app is running.