# How can I view Symfony log information in Cloudbees?

Tags: php, symfony, cloudbees

I've created a symphony based PHP application.  I'm trying to run my application on Cloydbees. Couldbees doesn't natively support symfony so I've also created my own clickStack.

When I load up the web page All it says is:

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please e-mail us at [email] an>d let us know what you were doing when this error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any inconvenience caused.

Since this is running on Cloudbees as far as I'm aware there's no file system access. So how Can I configure PHP/Symfony to log in such a way that it will be picked up so it will get displayed in the Log tab in the web interface?

**EDIT**

[Symfony-Clickstack](https://github.com/raystorm/Symfony-Clickstack)

According to: [How to use logback on Cloudbees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12724599/how-to-use-logback-on-cloudbees)
It looks like in order to write to the error log I need to print to **StdOut** and/or **StdErr**

I've tried configuring [monolog](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/index.html)
I've Tried:

- [Console](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog_console.html)
- ErrorLog
- Syslog

Here's the Logging Section of my config.yml

```
# Insert application logging   
monolog:
  handlers:
    syslog:
      type: syslog
      level: info  
    console:
      type:  console
      level: info
      verbosity_levels:
        VERBOSITY_NORMAL: NOTICE
    error_log:
            type:  stream
            level: info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Thanks to another Question I was able to get logging to work and I've now moved on to a new set of issues :)

The relevant MonoLog configuration is:

```
    stdout:
        type:  stream
        path:  "php://stdout"
        level: debug
```

Answer (score 1):

The current PHP ClickStack on CloudBees doesn´t support Symfony at this moment.

PHP is a part of the [Community Stacks](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/ClickStack), so it is not officially maintained by CloudBees team. However, this ClickStack could be updated adding Simfony in the near future.

Current GitHub repository, where you can see the way in which the stack is developed is available [here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/php-clickstack). If you would like to contribute, all the details are available on the [Wiki for Developers](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/DevelopingStacks).

Comment: I've extended the PHP clickstack, basing my work on the Drupal Clickstack, that extends the PHP one.  I've got it successfully grabbing web/app.php when I visit. It also seems to succesfukly run check.php while deploying, although it's not showing me the results :(.

Answer (score 0):

Check the `app/logs` directory. In it must be `dev.log` and `prod.log` files with errors, depending on what environment you use.

Comment: But the error is happening once deployed on Cloudbees, I don't have direct file system access.

Comment: You need it, there is not any other way to see

Comment: What about [Monolog](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html)?

Comment: You need to direct access to files. But if you has it, you may to see `app/logs`

Comment: What about `app_dev.php`? try to get this error page via `/app_dev.php/your_error_page`

Comment: app_dev.php returns `forbidden you don't have permission to access / on this server.`

Comment: It allow access only from `localhost`, need to add your IP in `it`